# Technique for evaluating Limits of recursive sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I was trying to evaluate the limit of a Recursive Sequence, and I found the following website on how to do so: [Evaluating Limits of Recursive Sequences](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/evaluating-limits-of-recursive-sequences).

They used one strange trick in order to evaluate the limit. The process basically is the following:
Let's define the following sequence:

$$\begin{cases}
a_1=k \\
a_{n+1}=f(a_n)
\end{cases}$$

And they basically did the following: $L = \lim a_{n+1} =\underbrace{ \lim f(a_n)= f(\lim a_n) }_{(1)}= f(L)$.

And so the limit would be the solution of the equation $L = f(L)$.

My question is, is this a correct way of evaluating these kinds of limits? Does it always work? If this is correct what are the cases where we can use this? What if this equation has multiple solutions? If the equation does not have any solutions does it mean that the limit does not exist? I'm looking for an analysis of this technique.

I think that in order to do step $(1)$ we need to make sure that $f$ is continuous at $L$, but I'm not sure.

Comment: It's correct if the limit exists.

Comment: On second thought I think you are correct $f$ must also be continuous at $L$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think that I sorta figured it out:

$$\begin{cases}
a_1 = k \\
a_{n +1} = f(a_n)
\end{cases}$$

Is actually the orbit of $k$ by $f$. This means that if it converges, then it's limit $L$ is a fixed point of $f$, meaning that:

$$L = f(L)$$

If this equation has multiple solutions then, if the sequence converges, one of them should be the limit, and if this has no solutions, then it's impossible for the sequence to converge. This equation having solutions does not imply that the sequence converges, it just means that if it does, then it's limit is one of those values.

Is this correct?